# Convert to C++17 nested namespaces in clang-format?

Tags: c++, c++17, clang-format

I am trying to enable clang-format for the first time in a codebase.  We are already using clang-tidy to check for code smells, and it has started warning us on code like this:

`namespace foo { namespace bar {`

or

```
namespace foo {
    namespace bar {
```

with the [modernize-concat-nested-namespaces](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/modernize-concat-nested-namespaces.html) check.  It wants to see

`namespace foo::bar {`

I was hopeful that running clang-format could fix this for me, but no dice.  Is there a way to do this with clang-format?

Comment: clang-tidy can fix this for you, clang-format only does whitespace.

Comment: @Barry, feel free to submit this as an answer and I'll be happy to accept it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't want to steal @Barry's answer (from comment on the original question), but it's been 4 months... It is true that `clang-tidy` can fix this for you, and `clang-format` mostly does whitespace and won't fix this for you.

For `clang-tidy`, you would do this:

```
clang-tidy -checks='-*,modernize-concat-nested-namespaces' -fix myfile.cpp
```

Explanation:

- The `-*` disables all checks.
- The subsequent `modernize-concat-nested-namespaces` enables that check.
- The `-fix` tells `clang-tidy` to fix any issues found, but only if there are no compilation errors. To force it to fix the issue even if there are compilation errors, use `-fix-errors`.

You can specify multiple source files on the command-line if you want to.